# How to count the rows by created_at columns with two tables in laravel query builder or eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have call_logs and jobseekers tables.Both tables have created_at column.And there is jobseeker_id in call_logs table.

In Jobseeker.php

```
    public function calllogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Calllog','jobseeker_id');
}
```

In Calllog.php

```
    public function jobseeker()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobseeker','jobseeker_id');
}
```

I want to show a table like

```html
created_at                          call_logs            jobseekers                         
----------------------------------- ---------------------------------
2017-08-05                                1                   3
2017-08-04                                2                   2  
2017-08-03                                3                   1
2017-08-02                                2                   4
2017-08-01                                5                   8
```

So, I can track the record, how many call_logs and how many new jobseekers in each day.
Here is how i tried in one table, its work well.But I want to make two tables at once query,

```
$count = DB::table('calllogs')
         ->select('created_at', DB::raw('count(*) as calllogs'))
         ->get();
```

it can show me, like

```html
created_at                        calllogs
----------------------------------- ----------
2017-08-03                            2
2017-08-04                             3
2017-08-05                            8
2017-08-06                            6
```

So please guide me a way to do ? Should I use union? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your models, and relationships.

Comment: I updated,please check it, @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways how to approach this. Both require a bit of coding.

Firstly you make 2 different queries, for example make this query as well.

```
$count2 = DB::table('jobseekers')
         ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as created_at'), DB::raw('count(*) as jobseekers'))      
         ->groupBy(created_at'))
         ->get();
```

Now you align the counts by day and show it in the table.

Other option is to make query for each day and count entries for calllogs and jobseekers on that day.

```
$start_date = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
$end_date   = Carbon::now()->now();
$dates      = [];

for ( $date = $start_date; $date->lte( $end_date ); $date->addDay() ) {
    $dates[] = $date);
}

$counts = [];
foreach ( $dates as $date ) {
    $dateLater                          = $date->copy()->addDay();
    $callLogs                           = Calllog::whereBetween( [$date, $dateLater] )->count();
    $jobSeekers                         = Jobseeker::whereBetween( [$date, $dateLater] )->count();
    $counts[ $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ) ] = [ $callLogs, $jobSeekers ];
}
```

Here $counts has count of job seekers asd calllogs for every day in range.

Comment: Hi bro , thank you so much for your detail explaination, the first one , i tried and dd($count2) ,its showing like "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'neh_thit_app.calllogs.created_at'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `created_at`, count(*) as calllogs from `calllogs`)"

Comment: the second one, tried it and dd($counts) ,it showing like "(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function copy() on string" ,i dun understand that copy() means too, can you please help me to check it again, thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: Sorry for typos, coping from heart without testing in real app.

Copy() is used so that Carbon instance is not modified. Modified code so that $dates array now has Carbon instances instead of strings.

Modified first example also and added as created_at to group by clause.

Comment: Hi bro, thanks again for your fixed, the first one i tried it out, its showing like "(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as created_at' at line 1 (SQL: select `created_at`, count(*) as jobseekers from `jobseekers` group by CAST(created_at AS DATE) as created_at)
" again

Comment: for the second option,its showing like " (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/jobapp/app/Http/Controllers/ChecklistController.php on line 77" , any idea bro?  please help me to fixed it again.

Comment: Made fixed to both cases. Did not test to run though, hopefully no more typos.